# Azure AD and Identity Framework in a single MVC APP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I have a MVC5 application which has authentication and authorization  using ASP.net Identity. So all my roles, user profiles are stored in the application database. The application is managed by me. My company now wants to use Azure AD for authentication in the application. So the user will be able to login with their credentials. If the user is signing in for the first time then i want to create the user profile in my application database. I also want to use the the roles stored in my application database for authorization.

Can someone provide some guidelines on how I can achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link where the step by step guide is available for using Azure AD to accept sign up and sign in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp

Overall in summary below is the architecture diagram which you need to perform.

[image: 1) Create]

You could also use Azure AD B2C for allowing user to signup/sign through google, FB, Amazon and etc identity provider.

All the authentication login you could implement it in filter and later you can decorate your controller with the AUTH filter.

and  then you can register your filter like below

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

I have not provided code samples here as it would be too long answer.

Coming back to your original question , **i want to create the user profile in my application database**  , basically after successful login you can save the claims data which would act as a user profile in your DB.

However it is not recommened to save the entire profile in database if you are already maintaining it in Azure AD.

Azure AD B2C gives the flexibility to add custom attributes too.

Hope it helps.Let me know if you need any help.